# How to Solve[] for rational constants?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system equations for rational, constant coefficients:

```
ord = 3;
vars = {a, b, c, d, e};
Do[tt[nn] = Total[vars^nn], {nn, 1, ord}];
mm = (Expand[tt[1]^ord] /. mm_^nn_ -> 0)/ord! // Expand; (*Sum of products of all unique sets of 3*)
expr = cc[1]*tt[1]^3 + cc[2]*tt[2]*tt[1] + cc[3]*tt[3] - mm;
aa = Solve[{expr == 0}, {cc[1], cc[2], cc[3]}]

(*{{cc[3] -> -((-a b c - a b d - a c d - b c d - a b e - a c e - b c e - a d e - b d e - c d e)/(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 + e^3)) - ((a + b + c + d + e)^3 cc[1])/(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 + e^3) - ((a + b + c + d + e) (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2) cc[2])/(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 + e^3)}} *)
```

This is the correct result for an under-determined system like this one, with 1 eqn and 3 unknowns.  However, if we require that the cc[]'s be rational constants, i.e. independent of {a, b, c, d, e}, then the only solution (which I calculated by hand) is:

```
bb = {cc[1] -> 1/6, cc[2] -> -1/2, cc[3] -> 1/3};
expr /. bb // Expand

(* 0 *)
```

How can I get such solns from MMa?  How does one impose the condition that the soln coefficients must be rational constants?

Ultimately, I need to do this with arbitrarily large vars lists and larger values of ord where ord < Length[vars].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at `SolveAlways` ([documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html)). In this case:

```
SolveAlways[expr == 0, vars]
(* Out: {{cc[1] -> 1/6, cc[2] -> -(1/2), cc[3] -> 1/3}} *)
```

---

It may be, however, that in a more complicated expression you might obtain multiple sets of values for the parameters, and you may have to refine the results to pick those in which all `cc[]` parameters are rational.

`SolveAlways` is actually just a "shortcut" for the following `Solve` expression (see the "Details and Options" section of its documentation):

```
SolveAlways[expr == 0, vars]
(* is equivalent to *)
Solve[!Eliminate[!expr == 0, vars], Array[cc, 3]]
```

so you could use the version written with `Solve` and explicitly request that solutions be rational by specifying a domain:

```
Solve[!Eliminate[!expr == 0, vars], Array[cc, 3], Rationals]
```

Comment: Why can't all Answers be this simple?  Thanks!

Comment: @JerryGuern glad it helped, and thank you for the accept!

Comment: I have never seen exclamation points used the way you've used them in the code you added.  Is "!expr==0" the same a "expr!=0"?  What do the two !'s in that code do?  Very intriguing.